# Scala-xml - XML.loadFile does not preserve attribute order

Tags: xml, scala

I'm using scala-xml to do some processing on some xml test files. I've noticed that when I read the file with XML.loadFile(file) and then save it back to the test file, the attributes of a node are sorted in ascending order. Is this a bug or is there a way to preserve the original ordering?

I am using "scala-xml" % "1.0.2"
Thanks!

Comment: In XML, the order of attributes is not relevant. If you are using a piece of software that depends on a certain order of attributes, you should rather throw out that piece of software, and replace it with something that is XML compliant. I'm not sure what you meant with "the test file" in your question. Overwriting a file with its own contents seems pointless at first sight.

Comment: We have an in-house test tool which runs these test files which contain xml messages. The tool sends these message to another system, waits for the response and then compares the actual response with whatever is specified in the file. I'll have to have a look at the code for this tool to see how it performs the comparison. Thanks for the response!